# theme options echoing multiple times

Tags: php, mysql, theme-options, theme-twenty-eleven

<strike>I tried to strip down the Twenty Eleven theme options page and add my own fields</strike> correction: I followed a tutorial somewhere, but when I try to echo the data, it comes out multiple times.

Here is my theme-options.php: http://pastebin.com/HSZM56jA

This is how I am echoing it:

```
<?php
    $options = get_option('gavsiu_theme_options');
    echo $options['message-primary'];
    echo $options['message-secondary'];
?>
```

It comes out 11 times.

> This is the main message.This is the secondary message. This is the main message.This is the secondary message. This is the main message.This is the secondary message. This is the main message.This is the secondary message. This is the main message.This is the secondary message. This is the main message.This is the secondary message. This is the main message.This is the secondary message. This is the main message.This is the secondary message. This is the main message.This is the secondary message. This is the main message.This is the secondary message. This is the main message.This is the secondary message.

I checked mySQL and the data is saved once. There is no duplication or error in saving the sentences.

print_r $options reveals that it prints out the array numerous times, so when I echo 'message-primary', it echoes each match from each array.

---

I'm echoing this in the front page. Saving the fields again did not change anything.

As I said, it is saved correctly into the database. In `wp_options` > `gavsiu_theme_options` :

```
a:2:{s:15:"message-primary";s:25:"This is the main message.";s:17:"message-secondary";s:30:"This is the secondary message.";}
```

Comment: (+1) for writing a good to read and detailed Q. Short Q: Where do you echo the data? Further: Does this value increase with each save? In this case I'd say you're saving it wrong.

Comment: are you perhaps echoing the options inside the WordPress loop? I've pasted your code into an empty theme and I don't see this same behavior.

Comment: That may be the problem. I have to go to work now so I can't check. If I were to echo this in a loop, how can I only echo 1 instance?

Comment: check `if( $wp_query->current_post == 0 )` to only output it in the first iteration of the loop.

Comment: Milo, your solution worked. Thanks. You should put it as an answer so I can accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The options are being output within the loop, so are being repeated for each iteration of the loop.

To check within the loop and only output something on the first iteration:

```
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

    if( $wp_query->current_post == 0 ):
        // this is the first post
        // output your options
    endif;

    // other loop stuff, title, content, etc.

endwhile;
```

similarly, to check if you are on the *last* post of the loop:

```
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

    if( $wp_query->current_post == ( $wp_query->post_count - 1 ) ):
        // this is the last post
    endif;

endwhile;
```

Comment: I have since moved the content out of the loop so I don't have to add the extra code.